# How to disable spring cloud zookeeper when executing integration test

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-zookeeper

The integration test tries to connect to zookeeper, when I test my code with `TestRestTemplate` and `spring-cloud-zookeeper-discovery` dependency. If zookeeper is not running the test throws an exception.

Here is simple project where you can reproduce the problem https://github.com/DenisGlot/disable-zookeeper-when-testing

How can I make the test skip connecting to zookeeper part?

Answer (score 2):

Added `bootstrap.properties` in test/java/resources and put there

```
spring.cloud.service-registry.auto-registration.enabled=false
spring.cloud.zookeeper.discovery.enabled=false
spring.cloud.zookeeper.discovery.register=false
```